# How can I disable all NFC-based cards on iPhone when my app is in foreground?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, nfc

My Application uses camera and when any other iPhone comes near it, the camera session gets interrupted due to the proximity cards that popup like device setup, namedrop, airdrop and AirPods setup etc.
Is there a way to disable all NFC based interactions for our iOS apps?
I looked at `requestAutomaticPassPresentationSuppression` But it looks like it's only for Apple Pay cards.
I need something generic.

Comment: I don't believe that there is any way for your app to stop this. The user can. Turn off Bluetooth.

Comment: This is a bit odd. Background tag reading is supposed to be [specifically disabled when the camera is in use](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/adding_support_for_background_tag_reading). This sounds like an OS bug, and I recommend opening a FB about it.

Comment: What's an FB? A bug report of some sort with Apple?